# Make inputfield clickable everywhere inside button-div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m implementing a FileUpload and have created `<div>` with bootstrap button class to make it look better.

But since I did this the `input` is just clickable at a specific position (above 'aufnehmen').

Can someone tell me how to make the Window open when clicking anywhere on the div?

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates my problem.

```css
.btn-lg{
    font-size: 36px !important;
}

.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        <span>Foto aufnehmen</span>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sampleFile" id="cameraImg" class="upload" onchange="processImg(this)"
               value="">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `label` instead of `div` to wrap file input.

```
<label for="cameraImg">
```

```css
.btn-lg {
  font-size: 36px !important;
}
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label for="cameraImg" class="fileUpload btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  <span>Foto aufnehmen</span>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sampleFile" id="cameraImg" class="upload" onchange="processImg(this)" value="">
</label>
```

Comment: Also a good solution, but I took the one from @RoryMcCrossan , because I didn´t had to change the div with a label. thanks anyway!

Comment: Wrapping `inputs` in `labels` is good practice, anyways happy coding.

Comment: Ah, I´ve googled what you said and it seems to be right. Then I will go for the good practice! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Glad! I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You got a bunch of answers to your problem quickly, but I think it is also important to show you how we found out what the problem is in such a short time, that is, how to debug such problems generally.

If you inspect the element(s) in your developer console and hover over it in the code, you can see the outlines highlighted.

[image]

That way, you can see that the input element itself is not as high as the button and that's why any click outside of that area didn't trigger the input's click event.

From that point on, you could have come up with your own solution (setting `height: 100%` as some answers suggested, or also `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. For the future I will keep this in Mind!

Comment: great description. Wish I could upvote this twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by setting `height: 100%` on the `input`:

```css
.btn-lg {
  font-size: 36px !important;
}
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  height: 100%; /* add this rule */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  <span>Foto aufnehmen</span>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sampleFile" id="cameraImg" class="upload" onchange="processImg(this)" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Decided to choose yours, because I just had to add one rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.fileUpload input.upload {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set  `width:100%; height:100%`; for input.upload it works... check below snippet

```css
.btn-lg{
    font-size: 36px !important;
}

.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        <span>Foto aufnehmen</span>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sampleFile" id="cameraImg" class="upload" onchange="processImg(this)"
               value="">
    </div>
```